# Is number of children categorical data?

Tags: categorical-data

I am considering reading either Agresti's Categorical Data Analysis, or Long's Regression Models, but I want to know how much do these books limit themselves by focusing on 'categorical data'.

For example, if we have data on the number of children that a family has, is that categorical data? Or what if we have some plant with $X$ number of leaves, and we have data on the number of leaves remaining after $Y$ days. In this case, is it categorical? Since data can only take on the values $X, X-1, ...., 0$?

Comment: I'd say it was a count variable. Which you might consider to be categorical, or ordered categorical, but it has more information than ordered categorical. Long's book (at least the first edition, which is the one I'm familiar with) covers the case.

Comment: Counted data and categorical data go together. If you have categories, you count them in the first instance. The reference models for such counts  of categories start with the Poisson, binomial, multinomial, ... Those are the same reference models for a counted variable. Or consider it this way: there is a single category, child, and you are counting instances; so it's the same thing.

Comment: The second example (leaves remaining) is bounded above and below.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not. It's a discrete numerical variable.

Numerical variables are quantitative. In opposition, a categorical variable would be called qualitative, even if there's an intrinsic ordering to them (e.g. an ordered categorical variable).

Answer (score 1):

## **WARNING : I'm not an expert**

#### But here is my opinion anyway :

In fact, it depends on what you're trying to do with it.

Let's take two discrete variables with less than 10 possible values :

- The day of the week (7 possible values)
- The number people living in a house/appartment (let's say it will go from 1 to 7 too, in a really vast majority of cases)

Now let's imagine you want to make (really simple) models :

- A model predicting the number of people in a bar/pub given the day of the week
- A model predicting the expenses of a given house in food, per month, given the number of people living in it.

In the first case, our model will need to be complex if we give it the day as a non-categorical input. (Because it will need a function with high peaks thursdays and saturdays, for example, and a little peak friday, etc... It's far from being a simple line)
If we give it this data as a categorical feature, it will be way easier for it to fit the input, without having to use 4th degree polynomial functions, or something like that.

In the second case, it's the opposite : The cost for food given a certain amount of people isn't that unstable, and can easily be fitted with 1st/2nd degrees polynomial functions, as a non-categorical feature. Giving our model the input as a categorical feature doesn't make any sense, and will only make it more complex (going from a 1 dimension space to a 7 dimensions space).

In the case of the plant. It still depends on what you want to do with it, but... Let's say a tree can have up to 100,000 leaves, using it as a categorical feature would be overkill. (And we can easily assume that, whatever you want to make, a plant having 1236 leaves left won't be very different from another having 1239 of them). In this case, it is a discrete non-categorical feature.